# React Layout Components Best Practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am working on creating a dashboard in React, and I currently have the page component holding all of the state and managing the requests to the backend api. I am considering refactoring to pull requests out of the page component - for the purpose of keeping it purely presentational - and moving all api and data logic inside the dashboard widget components.

Although I believe this is supposed to be best practice, I am concerned about certain inefficiencies. One problem  I forsee is that the fetch requests will need to be memoised, otherwise some of the data shared by several of the components will be requested from the API multiple times.
Another issue I forsee is that each component requires a connection to the redux state store and I am not sure of the overhead of using 'connect' versus passing the props from a useState object.

Overall, am I mostly concerned about nothing? Is this the best way to approach this? Or should I retain some logic in the page component if it reduces the number of api calls/ redux connections?

Comment: To fix the issue you have about "multiple api requests" for the same data, you could check out the library "swr". It's a React hook that has built in caching and a ton of great features. You can use the hook in multiple components, but the actual data fetching will only happen once and they will all receive the fetched data. https://swr.vercel.app/ . I've been using this hook in an app that I'm currently building and it's pretty amazing.

Comment: Chris - I was looking for a caching library and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris this is a great comment. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [swr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swr) library turned out to work perfectly. I would suggest anyone who needs to memoise API requests made by different components use the swr library with a common endpoint string to ensure caching.